# What stops lightsabers from becoming super long?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber

What stops the energy produced at the hilt of the Lightsabers from extending ridiculously far?

The Lightsabers are generally sword length (or spear length for Darth Maul), so what keeps them that way?

Comment: I have a youth group, and we were discussing this. my thought is that the Kyber crystal focuses the energy... Somehow.

Comment: [Obligatory XKCD](https://xkcd.com/1433/)